# Understanding Dijkstra's Algo

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I am using this reference material: http://www.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs545/fall09/ShortestPath.prn.pdf

In page 3's last slide, it says we are relaxing the edges leaving from B. But at that point, there is no edge between B and E, eventhough B is considered in that slide! How is that possible? Is that a mistake of the author or did I missed something else?

**EDIT**

This is the algorithm (from that pdf):

[image]

And this is the example graph that I am talking about:

[image]

The aim is to get the shortest path between A and D.
At first, the starting vertex "A" is initialized with 0 weight. Then the rest of them are assigned with infinity. That you can see it from the algo's first 3 lines. Then, next a set "S" is created which is empty. We have the Q set which is a queue, which will hold all the vertices of the graph. We, first get the minimum weighted vertex from Q. During the first time, we will get the starting vertex itself here, because we have assigned 0 in the initialization and the rest of the vertices are having infinity. So, the smaller value is 0 and there by we gets the vertex A. We add this to the set "S". Then we will loop through all the adjacent vertices of this vertex "A" and we will check whether the weight of the vertex is greater than that of vertex "A". If so, the adjacent vertices weights are recalculated by adding the weight of the vertex "A" and the weight of the edge between the "A" and this adjacent vertex. This is continued till the set Q becomes empty.

That's the working which I understood.

The doubt is at this part:

[image]

How did we get the vertex "B", when we relax the edges leaving from the vertex "E" ? There is no edge between B and E!!!

I hope you got the idea regarding my issue now. I think you would be getting little more idea if you look at the pdf rather than my stupid explanation. Isn't it? :P That's why I put the link too in the beginning of this question!

Comment: In page 3's last slide, it says, `Relax all edges leaving E`.

Comment: The last slide on page 3 says “Relax all edges leaving E” (that's a copy'n'paste).  Did you misread it?  Or are you talking about the second slide on page 4?

Comment: Yes that's what I was talking. But look at that table below it. It is adding "7" underneath "B" and "11" underneath "D" ! Why adding B there? There is no edge leaving out of B!! That's what I was getting confused at!

Comment: As currently stated, the question is heavily dependent on the link, which is not particularly appropriate. Please rephrase it, or extract sufficient information from the link, so clicking on the link isn't necessary.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: When there is no edge between B and E you can think of it as having an edge with infinite weight, that way you try to relax, but will obviously come worse off, and the `if-then` condition of the relaxation step will not adjust the distance to E (or B, whatever comes first in the scenario).

Comment: But if you check the next slides in that pdf, you will be able to see that "B" is selected! And at the end, the shortest path it claims seems to be ACEBD !

Comment: No, `ACEBD` is merely the set (`S`) of all the "processed" nodes, it's not the path.

Comment: oh ok. So where does the shortest path's info is depicted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d[v]` means: the length of the shortest path between the node `v` and the starting point by going through nodes that are in `S` only.

Despite node E does not connect to B, we have learned from previous iterations that a path of length 7 exist from `A` to `B` by going through `A` and `C` only. We can certainly deduce that the same path exists by going through `A`, `C`, and `E` only.

Note that in the highlighted section of the code in the first slide, it updates `d[v]` only if a smaller value exists. If not, `d[v]` remains unchanged.

I have noticed that the OP is confused about `S`. I would like to add that in this algorithm, `S` is only useful in the sense that it can help explain what the program is doing. (I used it when I explained to you what `d[v]` means.) `S` has not effect on the program at all. The program works the same if you remove `S` from the program completely.

This program does NOT provide you the shortest path. It only tells you the length of the shortest path between the starting node and every node in the graph.

If you want to get the shortest path, the program need to be revised to add this feature. Here are the steps:

- In the then clause of the program, either before or after `d[v] = d[u] + w(u,v)`, add `p[v] = u`. This way, you have preserved information on how you got the current `d[v]`, i.e. by taking the shortest path to `u` and then take edge `u->v`.
- After the whole program finishes (i.e. after the while loop), say you want to know what the shortest path is from A to B. You will find out that `p[B]=C`, and then you will find out that `p[C]=A`. Therefore, the path is `ACB`.

Comment: Thanks. So, where does the shortest path's info could be found? d[D] is 9 at the end of the iterations. That is the shortest path's weight. But how do we get the path from it?

Comment: You don't from the algorithm you presented above. You can get it by making some small modifications to the program. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Oh I see. Got it now. Thanks. I was thinking that we were trying to find the shortest path from it! It's just confusing when we look at the algos. Lost my whole day yesterday trying to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks got it now. Can you please help me with the Correctness I & II from that pdf also? I will create another thread with the details and will include what I understood from that two slides.

Comment: I have created another thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267921/correctness-i-in-dijkstras-algo